# Embed web app into a desktop application

Tags: application-development

Is there a way to embed a website/web app inside a application package?
(Something similar to phonegap but for linux distros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebKitGTK+](http://webkitgtk.org/) is the port of the portable web rendering engine WebKit to the GTK+ platform. Random tidbits about WebKitGTK+ can be found at [GNOME's Wiki](https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk).